# Timeout in c# tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

Can anyone tell if finally is always executed after a test times out or not.

```
[Timeout(1000)][TestMethod]
public void test()
{
  try
  {
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
  }
  finally
  {
     //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried it? What is the result?

Comment: @Schaliasos in vs 2010 it is executed, while in 2012 it is not...was wondering what is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Finally is executed **always**, doesn't matter if u have try/catch/ block, it is executed when any of those are finished

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use the TestCleanUp method in order to do work after the test if it is subject to timeouts.

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation to add a comment to Schaliasos's answer. As far as I know, Test Timeouts do not apply during Debugging sessions.