# Finally block is executed only on Debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

Question is taken from here: [SO - Timeout in c# tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514672/timeout-in-c-sharp-tests)

I created a simple unit test like this:

```
[Timeout(1000)][TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executed");
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the finally block is not executed. But when I debug it, it does. Why is this happening?

Comment: perhaps problem is in `Console.Writeline` - check solution provided in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461808/how-to-console-writeline-from-testmethod)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify the test timeout at **1000** ms, while your method sleeps for **2000** ms. This results in your test method being prematurely force-closed by the test framework, so it doesn't leave the `Sleep` call and doesn't have time to reach `finally` block. Debugging probably disables the timeout attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The Timeout attribute simply does not apply to Debugging sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Timeout is disabled during debugging, so you get to see Console.WriteLine() output.

But i still think finally is executed in vs2010. If you try to show a message box System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("finally") you should be able to see it pops up.

Console.WriteLine output is lost after timeout in vs2010.